# how does the jupyter notebook runs the python in browser the process runs behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, jupyter-notebook, kernel

recently i was asked for a R&D process which was about researching about how the jupyter notebook runs and what things runs behind the scenes and i achieved to find some solutions but the major thing in this process was the running of python code in browser that had no request and responses to any endpoint or url and it compiles the python code internally in browser
the question is how the python code executes in browser

thanks

Comment: This question needs a little tidying to be useful to future users. When writing a question aim to make the title short and the content directly on point. 
In this case, something like, 'when I am running a program in Jupyter' is Python run within the browser? 
The answer to that is 'No', Python is called by the browser. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear. However, taking "the question is how the python code executes in browser" as the question.

Run a terminal and issue 'top'. This will show you all the running processes. Now, whilst watching 'top', run a program in Jupyter. You will see, that 'Python3.6' or similar running as a process so long as your program is running.

Hence, the answer is, that the Jupyter page in the Browser calls Python to run the program with the output redirected to the browser panel.

You can do this on a Mac or on Linux, on a PC, almost certainly, there is a similar utility to 'top'. I just do not know in the case of a PC what that utility is called. Possibly, 'Task Viewer' would be OK.